# IdentityTVM responds with error in Amazon iOS SDK sample

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I am developing an iOS application to use Amazon cloud services(S3 service).

Since i need to authenticate the user, deployed TokenVendingMachine in AWS Elastic BeanStalk as per the steps provided in the [Token Vending Machine for Identity Registration - Sample Java Web Application](http://aws.amazon.com/code/7351543942956566)

But when iam trying to login through TVM, getting an error "signature doesn't matching".

Please see the log from BeanStalk section.

```
 an 29, 2014 6:15:38 AM com.amazonaws.tvm.Utilities getEndPoint
INFO: Endpoint : <endpoint url>
Jan 29, 2014 6:15:38 AM com.amazonaws.tvm.identity.LoginServlet processRequest
INFO: username : <username>
Jan 29, 2014 6:15:39 AM com.amazonaws.tvm.identity.LoginServlet processRequest
INFO: timestamp : 2014-01-29T06%3A15%3A38Z
Jan 29, 2014 6:15:39 AM com.amazonaws.tvm.identity.LoginServlet processRequest
INFO: uid : 38abccd49ff9f8ffe6c84c466f83ecae
Jan 29, 2014 6:15:39 AM com.amazonaws.tvm.identity.LoginServlet processRequest
INFO: endpoint : synopsislibrary.elasticbeanstalk.com
Jan 29, 2014 6:15:39 AM com.amazonaws.tvm.identity.IdentityTokenVendingMachine validateLoginRequest
FINE: Timestamp [ 2014-01-29T06:15:38Z ] is valid
Jan 29, 2014 6:15:39 AM com.amazonaws.tvm.Utilities sign
SEVERE: Exception during sign
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.amazonaws.tvm.Utilities.sign(Utilities.java:73)
    at com.amazonaws.tvm.custom.UserAuthentication.authenticateUserSignature(UserAuthentication.java:178)
    at com.amazonaws.tvm.identity.IdentityTokenVendingMachine.validateLoginRequest(IdentityTokenVendingMachine.java:174)
    at com.amazonaws.tvm.identity.LoginServlet.processRequest(LoginServlet.java:51)
    at com.amazonaws.tvm.RootServlet.doGet(RootServlet.java:38)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:680)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Jan 29, 2014 6:15:39 AM com.amazonaws.tvm.identity.IdentityTokenVendingMachine validateLoginRequest
WARNING: Client signature : e57edd8acbcbbfde0809575acbb5b644ee3713c861276937e35aeee2629129e3 doesnot match with server generated signature .Setting Http status code 401
```

I need clarification on few things

1. Do we need to make any modification on the WAR file associated with IdentityTVM template application? (Assuming, need modification in TokenVendingMachinePolicy.json file, please advice?)
2. Is there any relation between IAM user policy and TVM policy, should we give special attention to these sections while creating TVM in elastic beanstalk?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In answer to point 2: Yes, the TVM policy needs to be a subset of the IAM policy.  It is important to make sure that both your IAM and TVM policy are restricted those services and resources necessary for your application.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of places you can look at:

- when you create a new account, avoid using special characters like @, ?, etc. The sample code doesn't sanitize user name, and may have an issue dealing with special characters.
- make sure you entered the same user name/password combination as one that you created.
- this [blog post](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx371Y7CA0QJ95X/Simplifying-Token-Vending-Machine-Deployment-with-AWS-CloudFormation) simplifies TVM deployment process. It's worth a try.